# Problem with onflow nft-catalog Example 5

Tags: onflow-cadence

I'm trying to use the first script from example 5 here https://github.com/onflow/nft-catalog but it throws an error

[image]

This is the code

```
import MetadataViews from 0x1d7e57aa55817448
import NFTCatalog from 0x49a7cda3a1eecc29
import NFTRetrieval from 0x49a7cda3a1eecc29

pub fun main(ownerAddress: Address) : {String : [UInt64]} {
    let account = getAuthAccount(ownerAddress)

    let items : {String : [UInt64]} = {}

    NFTCatalog.forEachCatalogKey(fun (collectionIdentifier: String):Bool {
        let value = NFTCatalog.getCatalogEntry(collectionIdentifier: collectionIdentifier)!
        let tempPathStr = "catalogIDs".concat(key)
        let tempPublicPath = PublicPath(identifier: tempPathStr)!
        account.link<&{MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>(
            tempPublicPath,
            target: value.collectionData.storagePath
        )

        let collectionCap = account.getCapability<&AnyResource{MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>(tempPublicPath)
        if !collectionCap.check() {
            return true
        }

        let ids = NFTRetrieval.getNFTIDsFromCap(collectionIdentifier : key, collectionCap : collectionCap)

        if ids.length > 0 {
            items[key] = ids
        }
        return true
    }
    return items

}
```

Does anyone know what the problem with this is?